# PHP-FPM wasting CPU 100%

Tags: linux, lighttpd, php-fpm

I ran

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.mywebsite.com/category/page
```

to test the lighttpd-php-fpm performances.

In this websites I have installed the last version of wordpress, the server is fast!

I'm checking CPU usage with **top** command.

I see 94-98-99% usage of the CPU, do I have to optimize something?

Could you give me some advices?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

are you using a php cache like apc? If so I'd try to install one and then re-do your tests.